# SQL query to reconstruct inherited EAV model

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression, entity-attribute-value

I have 5 tables in my database representing an inherited EAV model:

```
CREATE TABLE AttributeNames
    ("ID" int, "Name" varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO AttributeNames
    ("ID", "Name")
VALUES
    (1, 'Color'),
    (2, 'FuelType'),
    (3, 'Doors'),
    (4, 'Price')
;

CREATE TABLE MasterCars
    ("ID" int, "Name" varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO MasterCars
    ("ID", "Name")
VALUES
    (5, 'BMW'),
    (6, 'Audi'),
    (7, 'Ford')
;

CREATE TABLE MasterCarAttributes
    ("ID" int, "AttributeNameId" int, "Value" varchar(10), "MasterCarId" int)
;

INSERT INTO MasterCarAttributes
    ("ID", "AttributeNameId", "Value", "MasterCarId")
VALUES
    (100, 1, 'Red', 5),
    (101, 2, 'Gas', 5),
    (102, 3, '4', 5),
    (102, 4, '$100K', 5),
    (103, 1, 'Blue', 6),
    (104, 2, 'Diesel', 6),
    (105, 3, '3', 6),
    (106, 4, '$80k', 6),
    (107, 1, 'Green', 7),
    (108, 2, 'Diesel', 7),
    (109, 3, '5', 7),
    (110, 4, '$60k', 7)
;

CREATE TABLE LocalCars
    ("ID" int, "MasterCarId" int)
;

INSERT INTO LocalCars
    ("ID", "MasterCarId")
VALUES
    (8, '5'),
    (9, '6'),
    (10, NULL)
;

CREATE TABLE LocalCarAttributes
    ("ID" int, "AttributeNameId" int, "Value" varchar(6), "LocalCarId" int)
;

INSERT INTO LocalCarAttributes
    ("ID", "AttributeNameId", "Value", "LocalCarId")
VALUES
    (43, 1, 'Yellow', 8),
    (44, 3, '6', 9),
    (45, 1, 'Red', 10),
    (46, 2, 'Gas', 10),
    (47, 3, '2', 10),
    (48, 4, '$60k', 10)
;
```

I can retrieve all of master car attributes as follows:

```
SELECT MC.ID, MCA.AttributeNameId, MCA.Value
FROM MasterCars MC
left join MasterCarAttributes MCA on MC.ID = MCA.MasterCarId
order by MC.ID;
```

Likewise, I can retrieve all of the local car attributes as follows:

```
SELECT LC.ID, LCA.AttributeNameId, LCA.Value
FROM LocalCars LC
left join LocalCarAttributes LCA on LC.ID = LCA.LocalCarId
order by LC.ID;
```

If LocalCars.MasterCarId is not NULL, then that local car can inherit the attributes of that master car. A local car attribute with the same AttributeNameId overrides any master attribute with the same AttributeNameId.

So given the data above, I have 3 local cars each with 4 attributes (color, fuelType, doors, price). Inherited attribute values in bold:

Local Car Id = 1 (Yellow, **Gas**, **4**, **$100K**)

Local Car Id = 2 (**Blue**, **Diesel**, 6, **$80k**)

Local Car Id = 3 (Red, Gas, 2, $60k)

I'm trying to find the necessary joins required to join the two queries above together to give a complete set of local cars attributes, some inherited:

```
LocalCarId    AttributeNameId     Value
------------------------------------------
1             1                   Yellow
1             2                   Gas
1             3                   4
1             4                   $100K
2             1                   Blue
2             2                   Diesel
2             3                   6
2             4                   $80K
3             1                   Red
3             2                   Gas
3             3                   2
3             4                   $60K
```

or possibly even:

```
LocalCarId    AttributeNameId     LocalValue         MasterValue
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    1             1                   Yellow        Red
    1             2                   NULL          Gas
    1             3                   NULL          4
    1             4                   NULL          $100K
    2             1                   NULL          Blue
    2             2                   NULL          Diesel
    2             3                   6             3
    2             4                   NULL          $80K
    3             1                   Red           NULL
    3             2                   Gas           NULL
    3             3                   2             NULL
    3             4                   $60K          NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by performing a union on all of your local car attributes and master car attributes. Each record is marked with an [IsMasterAttribute] flag. The next step is then use the ROW_NUMBER() window function to rank each of the duplicate attributes. The final step is to only select attributes which has a rank of 1.

```
    ;WITH CTE_CombinedAttributes
    AS
    (
        SELECT               1 AS IsMasterAttribute
                            ,LC.ID
                            ,MC.ID AS MasterCarId
                            ,MCA.AttributeNameId
                            ,MCA.Value
        FROM                 MasterCars MC
        LEFT OUTER JOIN     MasterCarAttributes MCA on MC.ID = MCA.MasterCarId
        INNER JOIN          LocalCars LC ON LC.MasterCarId = MC.ID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT               0 AS IsMasterAttribute
                            ,LC.ID
                            ,LC.MasterCarId
                            ,LCA.AttributeNameId
                            ,LCA.Value
        FROM                LocalCars LC
        LEFT OUTER JOIN     LocalCarAttributes LCA on LC.ID = LCA.LocalCarId
    )
    , 
    CTE_RankedAttributes
    AS
    (
        SELECT   [IsMasterAttribute]
                ,[ID]
                ,[AttributeNameId]
                ,[Value]
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID], [AttributeNameId] ORDER BY [IsMasterAttribute]) AS [AttributeRank]
        FROM    CTE_CombinedAttributes
    )
    SELECT       [IsMasterAttribute]
                ,[ID]
                ,[AttributeNameId]
                ,[Value]
    FROM        CTE_RankedAttributes
    WHERE       [AttributeRank] = 1
    ORDER BY    [ID]
```

The second output is also possible by performing a simple pivot on the final result:

```
    ;WITH CTE_CombinedAttributes
    AS
    (
        SELECT               1 AS IsMasterAttribute
                            ,LC.ID
                            ,MC.ID AS MasterCarId
                            ,MCA.AttributeNameId
                            ,MCA.Value
        FROM                 MasterCars MC
        LEFT OUTER JOIN     MasterCarAttributes MCA on MC.ID = MCA.MasterCarId
        INNER JOIN          LocalCars LC ON LC.MasterCarId = MC.ID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT               0 AS IsMasterAttribute
                            ,LC.ID
                            ,LC.MasterCarId
                            ,LCA.AttributeNameId
                            ,LCA.Value
        FROM                LocalCars LC
        LEFT OUTER JOIN     LocalCarAttributes LCA on LC.ID = LCA.LocalCarId
    )
    , 
    CTE_RankedAttributes
    AS
    (
        SELECT   [IsMasterAttribute]
                ,[ID]
                ,[AttributeNameId]
                ,[Value]
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID], [AttributeNameId] ORDER BY [IsMasterAttribute]) AS [AttributeRank]
        FROM    CTE_CombinedAttributes
    )
    SELECT       [ID]
                ,[AttributeNameId]
                ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsMasterAttribute]
                        WHEN 0 THEN [Value]
                    END
                 ) AS LocalValue
                ,MAX(
                    CASE [IsMasterAttribute]
                        WHEN 1 THEN [Value]
                    END
                 ) AS MasterValue
    FROM        CTE_RankedAttributes
    GROUP BY    [ID], [AttributeNameId]
    ORDER BY    [ID]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your time. I feel I'm very close to a solution now. My issue is that I should have elaborated that MasterCar.Id and LocalCar.Id can be completely independent values, and we can't synchronize them in our system. The union on MC.ID and LC.ID is causing an issue. I have updated the original script to have random Ids.

Comment: Hi David, does the “MasterCarId” column values in your LocalCars table tie back to your MasterCars table’s ID column. If that is the case then the query can be easily updated to give your what you want. If that is not the case then I don’t believe what you want is possible. 
I have updated my example with the assumption that the MasterCarID column does map back to your ID column in the MasterCars table.

Comment: Hi Edmond. Yes, sorry I had updated my script and didn't update the foreign key values in the LocalCars.MasterCarId column. Coding at 2am doesn't help :) Your query works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/23d49/3)**

```
SELECT LC."ID" as LocalCarID,   
       COALESCE(LCA."AttributeNameId", MCA."AttributeNameId") as "AttributeNameId",
       COALESCE(LCA."Value", MCA."Value") as "Value"
FROM LocalCars LC
LEFT JOIN MasterCars MC
       ON LC."MasterCarId" = MC."ID"
LEFT JOIN MasterCarAttributes MCA
       ON MC."ID" = MCA."MasterCarId"
LEFT JOIN LocalCarAttributes LCA
        ON (    MCA."AttributeNameId" = LCA."AttributeNameId"
             OR MCA."AttributeNameId" IS NULL)
             -- This is the important part
             -- Try to join with a MasterAtribute otherwise use the Car Atribute.
       AND LC."ID" = LCA."ID"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| LocalCarID | AttributeNameId |  Value |
|------------|-----------------|--------|
|          1 |               1 |   Blue |
|          1 |               2 |    Gas |
|          2 |               1 |  Green |
|          2 |               2 | Diesel |
```

Comment: There is something about this db schema I dont get. Why car 2 doesnt have master car? Because in that case you wont have master atributes and no where you guarantee the car has every attribute... like happen with car 1.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't generalize to my real model. The ID columns on the attributes tables can be completely random and so the LC."ID" = LCA."ID" clause isn't going to hold. My model is a bit difficult to explain, but a master and local car will have the same number of attributes, but some can be overridden on the local level.

Comment: @DavidJamesBall So you put an incomplete question and is my fault the answer isnt generic enough? I solve the question you make, if you have a different question then put some more effort in describe your real problem.

Comment: It wasn't incomplete, it was just a small sample of data. Apologies if I didn't convey my problem thoroughly enough to explain that I'm looking for a generic query that can work on a much bigger set of data. I have edited my question.